# Multiple record select from Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have Access table as described below, now in search i have a text box used for search, it take input as string, so when i put in search suppose **bmw** then i get the search result correctly, but if i put **bmw suzuki** then i get nothing.

i am using this code to get the values from the databse:

```
string [] car_name;     
string allnames = "'" + String.Join("','", car_name) + "'";
 for (int k = 0; k < car_name.Length; k++)
            {
  oledbcommand cmd1= new oledbcommand("select * from table1 where name in (" + allnames + ",myconnection)
  cmd1.exectuenonquery();
```

this is the table structure:

```
id  name keywords
1   cars  bmw

2   cars  toyota

3   cars  suzuki

4   truck bmw

5   truck scania

6   jeeps bmw

7   jeeps suzuki
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be missing the closing paren - ) - from your SQL statement:

```
oledbcommand cmd1= new oledbcommand("select * from table1 where name in (" + allnames + ")",myconnection)
```

Comment: I think that combined with the ExecuteNonQuery is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL looks fine, but why are you calling ExecuteNonQuery?  That is for inserts, updates, and deletes; it won't return any row data.  You need to call ExecuteReader or switch to a data adapter and fill a dataset.

Also make sure your IN statement is properly quoted.  It should be IN ('value1','value2')

`select * from table1 where name in ('BMW','Audi')` should be what gets set as the command text.

Comment: I do not want to use the constant values, i get what you said, but i tried this and it doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use OR statment... Like here:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE FirstName='Tove'
OR FirstName='Ola'
```

Comment: i m querying on just one column can you read the sql statement and i do not need or? thanks

Comment: This is not a good idea, you could end up with more ORs than any sensible person would want. IN, which is what safi is using, is definitely the best bet.